# arrow function shorthand for returning an object

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Im using the shortened ES6 arrow function notation to write my function body like this

```
const funcName = (...args) => something
```

I'm not even using a single curly bracket since my function body has just 1 return statement.

But say I want to return an object from this function, I would have to do:

```
const funcName = (...args) => {key:val}
```

The problem here is babel is assuming that the stuff inside the curly brackets is a function body - not an object - how to make it think that it is indeed an object??

Answer (score 5):

Embrace it with brackets

```
const funcName = (...args) => ({key:val})
```

Comment: ohhk, just checked it! it works thanks